# JSON/XML Document parsing in MongoDB Function

Tags: mongodb

I wrote a function in Mongo DB which will parse a give JSON/XML document and give me object.
I will use that function for further processing. 
When i have JSON parse it thrown below error. Can you please suggest is there any way we can parse JSON/XML Document?

`invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: JSON is not defined nofile_b:11`

```
function (payload) {
    var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
    var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);

    return contact.firstname;
}
```

In Spring Java, i am using below code to invoke function

```
Object a  = mongoTemplate.getDb().eval(function);
```

Comment: var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var jsonObject =  eval('(' + jsontext + ')');
var contact = jsonObject.firstname;

Comment: did you have all jackson libs on your project settings?

Comment: Your JavaScript function isn't valid, it needs a name.  Did you create this exact function in the shell?